# make .natvis show SmartPointer<T> as static_cast<T*>(void*)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, natvis

`E2<T>` is a smart pointer.

To enable a tool-tip of `E2<T>->aField` when mouse hovers above it, I can create `.natvis` like :-

**.cpp**

```
class Blank{
    public: int sss=5;
};
template<class T> class E2 {
    public: T* operator->(){
        return static_cast<T*>(atDerive);
    }
    T* atDerive;          //#
};
int main(){
    Blank k2; k2.sss=32;
    E2<Blank> e2;
    e2.atDerive=&k2;
    e2->sss=4;
}
```

**.natvis**

```
  <Type Name="E2&lt;*&gt;">
    <SmartPointer Usage="Minimal">atDerive</SmartPointer>
  </Type>
```

**Result**

[image]

### Problem

The above approach doesn't work if the content `void*` is in the base class `E1`.

**.cpp**

```
class E1{
    public: void* atBase=nullptr;    //#
};
template<class T> class E2 : public E1{
    public: T* operator->(){
        return static_cast<T*>(atBase);
    }
};
int main(){
    Blank k; k.sss=31;
    E2<Blank> e2;
    e2.atBase=&k;
    e2->sss=4;
}
```

**.natvis** (not work - no tool-tip appear)

```
  <Type Name="E2&lt;*&gt;">
    <SmartPointer Usage="Minimal">atBase</SmartPointer>
  </Type>
```

### Question

How to modify `.natvis` to enable tool-tip to show `void*` that is in the base class (`E1`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a type cast from `void*` to template type `T` (you can get it as a $T1 in your .natvis file)

```
<Type Name="E2&lt;*&gt;">
  <SmartPointer Usage="Minimal">($T1*)atBase</SmartPointer>
  <DisplayString>{($T1*)atBase}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Comment: Nope, nothing especial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects

In the first `E2` you use typed pointer and `void*` in the second, but compiler couldn't derive nested (real) type from `void*`, so you need to do some type cast to tell the compiler what type to use.

Comment: HINT: ($T1*) in both lines is the c-style typecast mr NAE was referring to. This answer was key to figuring it out for GRPC RepeatedPtrField data-types.